# Obtener valores en javascript de un array de session en c#

Tags: javascript, c#

Buenas, me gustaría saber como puedo obtener los valores en javascript de una variable de Session de `c#` que contiene un array de strings .
El código es el siguiente:
`C#`:

```
if (Session["PolizasClientes_RowID"] != null)
{
  Session.Remove("PolizasClientes_RowID");
}
var array = lstPolizas.Where(x => x.POLIZA == row_id).Select(x => x.DNI).ToArray();
var array2 = lstPolizas.Where(x => x.POLIZA == row_id).Select(x => x.POLIZA).ToArray();
string dni= array[0];
string poliza = array2[0];

string[] arrays = new string[] { dni, poliza };
Session["PolizasClientes_RowID"] = arrays;
```

Código `javascript` para leer la función que no me funciona(me devuelve System.string[1] o algo asi si leo la session enteray si pongo el [0] me devuelve S):

```
var valores_sesion = '<%=Session["PolizasClientes_RowID"]%>';
//me devuelve System.string[1] o algo asi:
console.log(valores_sesion);
//me devuelve S
console.log(valores_sesion[0]);
//me devuelve S
console.log(valores_sesion[0][0]);
```

Si en vez de añadir a la session un array, añado un único valor si que funciona correctamente, es decir con un código en `c#`:

```
Session["PolizasClientes_RowID"] = arrays;
```

código en `javascript`:

```
var valores_sesion = '<%=Session["PolizasClientes_RowID"]%>';                 
console.log(valores_sesion);
```

El resultado es el dni correcto.

Comment: Deberías especificar si esto es webforms, MVC, Razor, Asp.Net, etc, agregando etiquetas a la pregunta. Una respuesta puede ser correcta o no dependiendo de eso y la idea es no hacer perder el tiempo respondiendo algo que no va a funcionar en la plataforma en la que estas desarrollando.

Comment: Porque utilizas session? Es porque lo necesitas resguardar al dato en alguna otra pagina mientras el usuario esta conectado? o simplemente para pasar los datos a a una pagina? como en este caso al script del cliente ? Esto seria util para orientar la respuesta o mejorarla

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esto:

```
<script>
    var valores_sesion = '<%= Session["PolizasClientes_RowID"].ToString() %>';
</script>
```

Si no funciona, hay una forma de iterar el array que guardas en la session haciendo algo como lo siguiente:

```
var values = [];

<% 
    foreach(var item in Session["PolizasClientes_RowID"] { 
%>    
       values.push('<%=item%>');    
<% 
    }
%>
```

Comment: Puedes explicar un poco mas tu respuesta, _¿Por que intentar con eso?, ¿Que hace `.ToString()`?_ como tal la respuesta puede resolver el problema pero es de baja calidad y puede terminar siendo votada negativamente o bien eliminada.

Comment: No , así tampoco funciona, imprime esto: System.String[]

Comment: bueno actualice la respuesta, espero te sirva.

Comment: la forma de la respuesta actualizada me da el siguiente error: la instruccion foreach no puede funcionar en variables de tipo object

Comment: Eso es porque Session["PolizasClientes_RowID"] va a retornar Object, así que antes de usarlo en un foreach tienes que hacer el casting. En cuanto a la solución con Javascript, ahí tendrías que retornar un json representando el array.

Answer (score 0):

Tiene dos opciones que se me vienen a la mente para realizar esta tarea de "Renderizar un array en C# en un array de Javascript"

- **OPCION 1:** Foreach (idem a lo ya proponen) Realizar un foreach para
  escribir o el array en javascript o ir agreando con push (tambien en
  javascript)
- **OPCION 2:** [Recomendacion] Serializar en JSON el array (aqui con JSON.NET nos puede ayudar facilmente)

Y tambien te comente un Tip/Recomendacion para trabajar con session (que dicho sea de paso habria que ver porque estas utilizando session)

- **Encapsular Session en Propiedades** (Para tener intellisense, y tipado session)

**¿Por que no funcionaba directamente escribiendo o ToString() de Session?
Antes que nada si haces  o tienes algo asi para escribir session  (o cualquier otro objeto que no tengo sobreescrito ToString())

```
<script> 
    var array1 = <%=Session["Array1Demo"] %>;
</script>
```

O que es lo mismo que colocar ToString()

```
<script> 
    var array1 = <%=Session["Array1Demo"].ToString() %>;
</script>
```

Vas a tener este resultado renderizado
    `var array1 = System.String[];`

Lo cual no es lo que estamos necesitando, ya que no renderiza a un array sino que *escribe el nombre del tipo de objeto que contiene la session*, el cual es el comportamiento por default del ToString() en object, escribe el nombre completo de la clase. 
*PEro se puede sobre escribir*, esto te dejo como inquietud para que lo investigues, ya que en lenguajes orientados a objetos se puede (cuando te deja la misma clase) definir un comportamiento diferente para una clase que hereda de  otra en un metodo.

Vamos a las opciones de renderizado...

**OPCION 1** Realizar un foreach para escribir o el array en javascript o ir agreando con push (tambien en javascript)
Aqui en vez de escribir un array estamos literalmente escribiendo el contenido de cada item para agregarlo en un array en javascript con PUSH, o incluso directamente armando la "cadena" del array. Si buen se lo puede hacer es un metodo un tanto "manual" teniendo en cuenta la opcion 2 que es la serializacion.

**OPCION 2** Serializar en JSON el array (con 
Aqui podemos utilizar `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Session["Array1Demo"]);`, veamos un ejemplo ayudandonos con una propiedad en un Webform

Tenemos una propiedad...

```
public string Data { get; set; }
```

Luego

```
Data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Session["Array1Demo"]);
```

Y renderizamos

```
<script> 
        var array1 = <%= Data %>;
    </script>
```

Y el render sera

```
<script> 
    var array1 = ["item1","item2","item3"];
</script>
```

Justo lo que estamos necesitando.

Tambien se podria tener todo en la vista

```
<script> 
    var array2 = <%=  Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Session["Array1Demo"]) %>;
</script>
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guía

Enlaces que te pueden ayudar

- [JsonConvert.SerializeObject](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeObject.htm) Serializes the specified object to a JSON string.